# How to play non default system sounds in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-experience, audio

I want to play system sounds with .NET code in my app - no problem if I want to use `Beep`, `Asterisk` etc as I can just use:

```
My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk)
```

But what if I want to play something like 'Menu Pop-up'? This sound is off by default in the Windows Default Sound Scheme, but if the user has set this sound up to do something then I want to play it.

The user could have assigned any wav file to this action so I want to find which (if any) sound they have assigned and play it. Compatibility with Windows versions back to XP is also essential.

Playing it of course is no issue either as I can use:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(strWAVFile)
```

So the question is really about how to find it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the question, but it seems you are asking "how can I play the sounds the user has selected for a certain event when the user hasn't selected any sound for that event?"

Comment: @Andrew I want to find if a sound has been assigned to the action 'Menu Pop-up' in control panel Sound. If a sound *has* been assigned then I want to find the path to the WAV file associated to this action.

Comment: Gotcha! I think Alex Essilfie's answer below is what you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave sound files for the system's events are stored in the system registry, and they have been there since Windows 95 so compatibility is not an issue.

Check this registry key for the sounds that are played for the events:

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default`

For 'Menu popup' like you said, you can read the default value from this registry key:

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\MenuPopup\.Current`

So you would write code like this:

```
Dim rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\" & _
                                         "MenuPopup\.Current")
Dim soundFile = rk.GetValue("")

If soundFile <> "" Then 
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(soundFile)
End If
```

I checked if the `soundFile` variable was empty before playing it because not every event might have a sound associated with it and you do not want your application to stop working because of a sound file that cannot be found.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was *hoping* for as I thought there might be a managed code solution, but this is definitely a workable solution.

Comment: @Matt: Since programs can add their own entries to the sound schemes, any attempt to wrap the entire operation in managed code may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming windows default media folder is in **`C\Windows\Media`**

You can simply play any sound that comes with Windows by default.

```
 My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\windows\media\alarm01.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

Have a fresh windows install and open Media folder.

> While coding pay attention to target windows compatibility.